# My question was closed as dupe of something I mentioned in my question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61484977/2071807) I mentioned at the bottom that it wasn't a dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60056208/loop-over-empty-iterator-does-not-raise-exception). But it was nevertheless unilaterally closed as a dupe of it by a gold-badge  holder.

The questions are about a similar area of syntax, but are asking for different answers about that area of syntax.

Surely it's ok to have different questions about the same area of syntax?

For context, I asked:

> What's a nice way of doing this in Python:
>
> ```
> i = 0
> for x in foo:
>     print x
>     i = i + 1
> print(f"We handled {i} (potentially zero) elements in foo")
> ```

and the other question asks why iterating over an empty iterator runs zero times.

I don't think these are the same question, although they both deal with iterating over empty iterators.

Do I have any recourse?

Comment: What is "doing this"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You edited the link after the question was closed.

Your recourse is to ensure your edit is substantial including **adding additional information as to why you think the duplicate does not answer the question**, otherwise [reviewers will only see this change](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/25986395) and decide it doesn't warrant reopening:

> [image]

Comment: Yes, that's helpful. I've made a more substantial change which puts right at the top what I want, and how it's different from the dupe, along with a good edit message. Didn't know there was a re-open queue. Thanks!